# OpenAi tokens consumed in generating response of a query from custom knowledge base

Tags: openai-api

I am using OpenAI API to build a chatbot based on data feed by me, its consuming more tokens as predicted by words count from query & response,what is the reason?

I provided the chatbot with file containing details about finals of fifa worldcup 2010,2014,2018,2022, and asked this question.

Question: `which worldcup final did croatia played?`

Chatbot response: `Croatia played in the 2018 FIFA World Cup Final.`

Tokens consumed (actual):

```
INFO:root:> [query] Total LLM token usage: 327 tokens
INFO:root:> [query] Total embedding token usage: 9 tokens
```

I was expecting less than 30 tokens for this Q&A.